# Is it okay to sleep with the wifi router next to me?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, biophysics, radio-frequency, microwaves

Where I sleep I have my wifi router right above me. I don't know if this is safe for my health since it emits radiation.

Some people say that it should be safe since the radiation emitted is non-ionising.

But other sources claim that even non-ionising radiation can have harmful effects biologically.

Therefore, I'm quite confused whether it is safe or not.

These articles claim that it is not safe:

https://educateemf.com/is-it-safe-to-sleep-near-a-wireless-router/

https://emfadvice.com/sleep-near-wifi-router/

https://techwellness.com/blogs/expertise/is-wifi-safe-distance-is-key-emf-protection

https://ictbuz.com/wifi-router-in-bedroom/

Some insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Major health effect is all the danged blinking lights keeping me awake. No worries from wifi frequencies.

Comment: They are all trying to sell you something, alarming you with "some people say"s and "some studies". Haven't you seen this before with G5 voodoo blather, radio waves in the 30s, etc?

Comment: @JonCuster  make a flap out of black paper over the lights

Comment: Apart from radiation, sometimes in  cold dry areas, static charge is developed between skin and bedsheets/blankets. This static charge can damage electronics. So its better to keep any electronics away from bed when you sleep, preferably at some wooden table.

Comment: I have just begun sleeping with a supposed 5G router slightly above and about 18 inches/45 cms from my head. If I smell anything cooking when I am sleeping or otherwise shouldn’t, I will let you know, assuming I am still able to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: If I were sleeping with my router directly above me, I would worry more about it falling on my head than about the radiation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to a biology site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wifi router, as well as cell phones and microwave ovens all produce non ionizing radiation. To date, the major concern for non ionizing radiation is its heating (thermal) effect on tissue. It is my understanding that the magnitude of the non ionizing radiation of wifi and cell phones is limited by regulations to be well below harmful in terms of heating of tissue. The leakage limits for microwave ovens is likewise  regulated to be well below harmful in terms of heating of tissue.

Insofar as the potential harmful non-thermal effects of these sources are concerned, research continues. Clearly, as the number of these sources continue to increase, more data will  be available to determine whether or not there are cumulative harmful non thermal effects of non ionizing radiation at the levels being produced.

In the meantime, in my opinion only, though it would seem prudent to limit ones exposure as much as practicable, it should not be because of being alarmed by non scientific information one may encounter on the internet. Rather it should be in recognition of the fact that the long term effects of non ionizing radiation continue to be studied.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your caution goes the same way as the fears. We live and walk in the cities where the effects of being hit by a car are known, and the probability of being hit by a car when crossing the street is known. Should we not cross the street? Drive a car?  Unknown risks because too small to be seen in studies now, should be way below the threshold of being prudent.

Comment: @annav I would argue the answer to all of the questions you raise can only be given with respect to benefits.  If there are no benefits, it is absolutely rational to avoid potential slight risks.  The reality is that there are benefits to the examples you give, and thus we keep driving and keep walking.

Comment: @CortAmmon what about sleeping in a limited space (money, situation etc)

Comment: @annav Then, as Bob D puts it, one should act in recognition of the fact that the long term effects of non ionizing radiation continue to be studied (and most likely sleep near the wifi).

Comment: This, of course, makes more sense using the Open World Assumption.  If not knowing a things is true is subtly different from knowing a thing is not true, Bob's answer makes sense.  If one uses a Closed World Assumption, where not knowing the risk is the same as knowing there is no risk, then the answer doesn't hold up as well.

Comment: There are also accepted statistical approaches for dealing with the grey area between the extremes of not knowing vs. knowing not.  While the OP probably doesn't want to invoke such rigorous tools here, it can be useful to know that there are approaches like [Bayesian Inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) which are designed to support rational decision making with imperfect information.

Comment: @CortAmmon It’s interesting to note that In the early 70s Consumer Reports position on microwave ovens (which were only recently introduced to the consumer) was “Not Recommended”.  It was based on what they called the unknown long term effects of low level microwave radiation.  History shows that consumers decided that the benefit of the new appliance outweighed the then unknown risks.

Comment: @CortAmmon There was an interesting book back then called “Of Acceptable Risk”. What is considered to be “acceptable risk” often comes down to a personal choice. I choose not to ride a motorcycle as I find the known risks unacceptable. You, on the other hand, may find the known risks acceptable and choose to ride one. One shoe size doesn’t fit all.

Comment: @annav See my comments to Cort